# Word choice - Redeem, Exchange, Use

Tags: word-choice, word-request

Let's say you are offering a package price for Service-A . It costs $10 which is equivalent to 10 credits. You provide the customer the flexibility to use the credits for other services you provide.

> Credits can be ***exchanged*** for Service-B
> Credits can be ***used*** for Service-B
> Credits is ***redeemable*** for Service-B

**Redeem**: gain or regain possession of (something) in exchange for payment.
**Exchange**: give something and receive something of the same kind in return.
**used**: take or consume (an amount) from a limited supply

Do the above words aptly describe the situation? Before checking the dictionary, I assume either *redeem* or *exchange* should be easily understood. After checking the dictionary, I have second thoughts about them and I do not know which word to use. Is *use* a better choice? Is there a more appropriate word to fit the context?

Answer (score 0):

*You provide the customer the flexibility to use the credits for other services you provide.*

> So we should use the word also or a word with a similar meaning.

*the flexibility to use the credits*

> Therefore we can use the credits for other services.

---

> *Credits can **also** be used for Service-B*

> *Credits have the flexibility of being redeemable **for both** Services-A & B*

> ***Credit use is flexible, they can also be exchanged for Service-B***